# MySQL Returning Column Names instead of their Content

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, sql, winforms

Okay, so in the past few weeks I've probably written about 40 select statements. So, I know how to do it. And I've just written another one, but this time I need to use ComboBox values to match against, and it keeps resulting in the names of the column (the right column, mind you), instead of what's inside the column.

```
string st = "SELECT '" + txtchange.Text + "' 
               FROM mysql_9269_dbase." + pages.Text + "";

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(st, msc);
cd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader msdr = cd.ExecuteReader();

while(msdr.Read())
{
   txt.Text = msdr[0].ToString();
}
```

Now, why is it returning the column name instead of the content of that column?

Comment: Why do you have single quotes around the value that is coming from txtchange.Text? Also, is txtchange a ComboBox control?

Comment: @rsbarro - I did explain what controls they were but looks like PMG Ponies removed it! - And yes, all controls in this snippet are combo box's. And regarding the single quotes. That's how I was taught, and it's what I've read in docs. Plus it works with my other select statements, and the query fails without them in this case.

Comment: @βӔḺṪẶⱫŌŔ I'm a SQL Server guy, but in SQL Server SELECT 'something' will just get you back 'something'. If you want to specify a column name you either say SELECT something or SELECT [something]. Looks like I'll need to install MySql so I can check this out myself.

Comment: @OMG Ponies  - You're right, the while loop is only returning one row. Originally I only had one row that it could return anyway. But, after reading your comment I added a few test rows, and it still only brought back one result, which was the name of the column.

Comment: I didn't remove anything about controls - only reformatted, and removed "Thank you".

Comment: @rsbarro. I'm sorry, you were right! I actually took out the quotes AND also removed the following line: "`cd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;`" - It wouldn't work before without the quotes. But after removing that other line and the quotes, it now works.

Comment: @OMG P, Hmm, sorry. I just saw your name where it says edited, and saw that Thank you was removed and the italicized text was removed. Maybe it's just not displaying, i'll check

Comment: Hmmm, it's not there anymore (the italicized text). Anyway, @rsbarro, you wanna make that your Answer so I can accept?

Comment: @βӔḺṪẶⱫŌŔ Someone already posted the same answer, I would accept that. Glad that worked for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lose the single quotes.

Change

```
  "SELECT '" + txtchange.Text + "' "
```

to

```
  "SELECT " + txtchange.Text + " "
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your answer! I was too busy writing comments! :$

Answer (score 1):

**In sql you can do it like this.**

string query = "Execute("+"'SELECT " + txtchange.Text + " FROM mysql_9269_dbase." + pages.Text + "')";

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Thanks.